# Copy files based on timestamp in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy files based on timestamp.

Example:

I have folder1 and folder2.
Files from folder1 should be copied to folder2 and then once a day all files from folder2 will be uploaded to the server.

Files get accumulated in folder1 every day hence I need to copy only *new* files and don't touch old ones.

My point: I want to use 'copy' command conditionally i.e. current day timestamp - 1. Then every day it will copy files from the day before only.
My question: how could I specify files created with timestamp  = [current day] - 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at Robocopy?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx

This might do the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to copy new files and you are using Windows 7 or higher you can use `robocopy`, which is designed for replicating directories and by default only copy/update new files (the `/E` option is for copying also subdirectories):

```
robocopy folder1 folder2 /E
```

This will copy only new files from folder1 to folder2, if there is no new files it won't copy anything.

Comment: Thanks Folks, It looks that robocopy has the option /MAXAGE:n. It might work for me. I have play with it and will report later. Thanks for suggestion